# how do you precompile ejs templates to file

Tags: ejs

So I wanted to precompile ejs templates into a .js file

```
var compiled = ejs.compile(source);
fs.writeFileSync(target, 'myTemplateFunction = ' + compiled);
```

but that serilalizes into

```
function (locals){
   return fn.call(this, locals, filters, utils.escape);
}
```

what's the best way to pre-compile and write ejs templates into a .js file

Answer (score 0):

You can create a templates.js file (either manually or in the code) as an empty module. Then after compiling templates, attached the compiled function onto the empty module.

```
var ejs = require('ejs');
var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFileSync('./template.js', 'module.exports = { }', 'utf8');

var compiled = ejs.compile(fs.readFileSync('./example.ejs', 'utf8'));

// Add an example function to the template file that uses the compiled function
require('./template').example = compiled;

// Get the example template again (this could be in another file for example)
var output = require('./template').example;
var html = output({ id: 10, title: 'Output' });
```

Since [modules are cached](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) by default, you should be able to `require('./template.js')` wherever you need and it will have all of the precompiled templates attached.

Comment: This is not related to serializing templates, which was the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

[Lodash _.template()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#template) method creates a string represention of the EJS template function during compilation and attaches it as *source* property to the compiled function. You can store that string into a JS file, embed it into HTML, or read it to your grandchildren before sleep.

For example:

```
> var _ = require('lodash');
> var compiled = _.template('Hi <%= user %>!');
> compiled({ user: 'Axel' })
"Hi Axel!"
> compiled.source
"function(obj) {
  obj || (obj = {});
  var __t, __p = '';
  with (obj) {
    __p += 'Hi' + ((__t = ( user )) == null ? '' : __t) + '!';
  }
  return __p
}"
> var fs = require('fs')
> var src = 'module.exports = ' + compiled.source;
> fs.writeFileSync('mylittlescript.js', src);
```

This approach is used by Webpack's [ejs-loader](https://github.com/okonet/ejs-loader) module. Note also that npm package [ejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs) does not provide such *source* property.

Answer (score 0):

```
const ejs = require("ejs");
const fs = require("fs");

let src = fs.readFileSync("test.ejs", "utf8");

let code =
    "const generate = " + ejs.compile(src, {client: true, rmWhitespace: true}) + ";" +
    "module.exports = { generate };";

fs.writeFileSync("test.js", code);
```

That `{client: true, ...}` will generate a standalone function, and we're assigning it to the name `generate` and exporting it, so we can use this generated `test.js` module like:

```
const test = require("./test");
let generated_html = test.generate({ message: "Yadda Boo" });
```